# How to parse image form data from FilePond

Tags: image, file-upload, next.js, filepond

I'm attempting to upload image files to my nextjs app where I'll eventually store in GCS but I'm having some trouble with the image form data. I'm using [FilePond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/) on the client to handle uploading the file and sending a req to a simple API that I have on the server.

```
// Component
import { FilePond, File, registerPlugin } from "react-filepond";
import FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation from 'filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation';
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from "filepond-plugin-image-preview";
registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation, FilePondPluginImagePreview);

const Page = () => {
    const [productImages, setProductImages] = useState<File[]>([]);
    return (
        <FilePond
          allowMultiple={true}
          maxFiles={2}
          files={productImages}
          onupdateFiles={setProductImages}
          server={{
            process: {
              url: "/api/upload",
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "mutlipart/form-data"
              },
              ondata: formData => {
                formData.append('image', "test-image");
                return formData;
              }
            }
          }}
        />
    );
};

export default Page;

// ./pages/api/upload
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

const Index = (_req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const reqBody = _req.body ?? null;
  console.log(_req);
  if (!reqBody) res.status(200).json({ message: "No request body found" });

  res.status(200).json({ data: "OK" });
};

export default Index;
```

The issue I'm seeing is the files are being sent as a giant blob string and I've seen other people be able to access the files property from the incoming request ([shown here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymO_r1hcIXk&t=181s)). This is my first time building a file uploading feature into any of my projects so I'm not entirely sure what's best practice for handling files from incoming requests and parsing them to be stored in some file storage service like GCP or S3.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to chunk the image file. set the configuration [chunkUploads](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/instance/properties/#server) to true.

Then your backend should process the chunked file like [this](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/#process-chunks).

Comment: I had a typo in the in the content-type field lol. I also ended up using formidable on the backend to help with parsing incoming form data.